# I want to show subtitles on osmf based grind player. I have did following things

Tags: html, actionscript-3, nginx

I have download source code of grind player from (https://github.com/kutu/GrindPlayer) and followed the steps given on that page. After I install nginx and create one html page to run Grind player. From grind player site (http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/docs/grind/#embed) I embed grind player in html page using swfobject. Now player is get added to my page and I am able to run video in grind player, but problem is I don't find out how do I add .srt file to be run in grind. As reference of following code of my html page, I added 'subtitle' variable and pass it to variable 'parameter' which is passed in swfobject. Please guide me where I am going wrong?

```
        // Collect query parameters in an object that we can
        // forward to SWFObject:
       var subtitles = JSON.stringify({
    subtitles: [
        {
              src: "Closedcaption_atsc_rollup.srt"   // url to .srt file
            , label: "English"          // label for subtitles, will show in menu
            , language:"en"             // optional
        }

    ]

    // optinal, configuration to display subtitles
    // all properties by default, you can change only what you need
    , config: {
        // fontSize, in percentage of available width
        // for GrindPlayer available width for subtitles is 70% of player width
        // ex: if player width is 1280px, then real fontSize will be
        // Math.floor(1280 * 0.7 * 0.035) = 31
         fontSize: 0.035
        , minFontSize: 20
        , maxFontSize: 36
        , textColor: 0xDFDFDF
        , bgColor: 0x101010
        , bgAlpha: 0.8
    }
}); 
            var pqs = new ParsedQueryString();
            var parameterNames = pqs.params(false);
            var parameters = {
                //src: "http://streambox.fr/playlists/test_001/stream.m3u8",
                //src: "http://localhost:8082/playlists/test_001/stream.m3u8",
        src:"mission.mp4",
        //src:"sample.mp4",
        //src:"galliyan.mp4",
                autoPlay: "true",
                verbose: true,
                controlBarAutoHide: "true",
                controlBarPosition: "bottom",
                poster: "images/poster.png",
                javascriptCallbackFunction: "jsbridge",
                plugin_hls: "../../bin/release/flashlsOSMF.swf",
                hls_minbufferlength: -1,
                hls_maxbufferlength: 300,
                hls_lowbufferlength: 3,
                hls_seekmode: "KEYFRAME",
                hls_startfromlevel: -1,
                hls_seekfromlevel: -1,
                hls_live_flushurlcache: false,
                hls_info: true,
                hls_debug: false,
                hls_debug2: false,
                hls_warn: true,
                hls_error: true,
                hls_fragmentloadmaxretry : -1,
                hls_manifestloadmaxretry : -1,
                hls_capleveltostage : false,
                hls_maxlevelcappingmode : "downscale",
            "src_http://kutu.ru/osmf/plugins/subtitles": encodeURIComponent(subtitles)
        };
```